# requestSubscription gives "Invalid product ID" on react-native-iap even though it works with getSubscription

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement in-app purchase on my iOS application and I am currently testing this feature through the application downloaded from TestFlight.

Here is the code (assuming the two product id are the same and supplied proper one)

```
    import * as RNIap from 'react-native-iap';

    const handlePlanPress = async () => {
        try {
            setProcessing(true);
            await RNIap.requestSubscription('sku', false);
        } catch (err) {
            const products: RNIap.Subscription[] = await RNIap.getSubscriptions(['sku']);
            console.log(err)
            console.log(products)
            Alert.alert(
                i18n.t('stay_tuned'),
                err.toString() + '\n' + 'available products:\n' + products.toString(),
                [
                    { text: 'OK', onPress: () => {} },
                    {
                        text: i18n.t('cancel'),
                        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
                    },
                ],
                { cancelable: false },
            );
            setProcessing(false);
        }
    }
```

`"react-native-iap": "^4.4.9"`

With the `console.log`, I can see the product information was printed locally for `getSubscriptions`, but `requestSubscription` function is giving me the error even on the app downloaded from TestFlight.

I have agreed with all the agreements on AppStoreConnect, and filled in the contact information for users.